# Computer couldn't connect to wifi network, but other devices can

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I've a Windows 10 computer and I would connect to my WiFi network from Telenet, but that's not possible. If I use an other device, the connection could be made with that network. If I try an other WiFi network on my computer, I could make a connection.

I've runnend the network checker. This are the issues:

[image]

Translation here:

> #### Problem solving is completed
>
> Couldn't solve the found problems automatically. Below you could find more details.
>
> **Found problems:**
>
> - **⛔️ Not solved:** The settings for the wireless security on this computer doesn't match with the settings on 'telenet-5314E38'.
> - **⚠️ Established:** A network cable isn't connected on the correct way or is possible damaged.

What must I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Try making your computer 'forget' about the network `telenet-5314E38`, then try connecting as though it were a new-to-your-computer network. If that doesn't work, you'll need to tell us more about the various WiFi-related settings on your computer, and on the network.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: It works by forgetting the network and connecting as a new network.

Comment: Which means that somehow the "remembered" settings and the network settings got mismatched - which is what the error message said - and doing the forget-and-reconnect set it up so that they match.

Answer (score 0):

Wierd, I've tried what @jeff said ant it works.

> Try making your computer 'forget' about the network telenet-5314E38, then try connecting as though it were a new-to-your-computer network